# how to handle the same signature for APP on Google Play Store and other Stores?

Tags: google-play, signature

I have published an APK on Google Play Store and let the Play Store to sign the application using its internal signing method. Now I want to distribute the app on all APK stores with the same signature.

Which method is the correct way to manage the situation?

1. Extract the signed APK from Google Play Store. (and how?)
2. Not using Play Store signature and use my own signature.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the Play signature on other App stores. If you want to distribute on other app stores you should use your own signature.